# Cannot access outlook pst files shared on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, network-share, outlook

We used to have a windows server (2K3) which is now a Ubuntu file server (samba), and all the files in other shared folders seem accessible and editable, apart from the ones in the outlook archive. They are actually accessible (browsable), but Outlook (2010) cannot "accessed" them once used as a data file.

It looks to me that it could be linked to the fact that the previous permissions related to our domain are not copied over because the new ubuntu server is not integrated into our domain but only in a workgroup (we don't really need specific rights for the shared folders on this server, so I thought it would be simpler to set up like this).

As well, even a `chmod 0777 *` and a `chown nobody.nogroup *` in the outlook archives folder does not set `Everyone` to `Full control` in Windows 7, what else could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue was not related to Ubuntu as this happened as well when moving the files to a windows computer.
We found a workaround: create a local .pst and use its inbox folder as the destination folder when retrieving emails, then just drag and drop the files into the network data file.

Answer (score 1):

There was some [older discussions](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-Guide/happy.html) about adding `veto oplock files = /*.pdf/*.PST/` to the smb.conf file.  That may help, or Microsoft may have changed the way Outlook 2010 accesses the .pst now.

Comment: Good shot, but does not seem to be working unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

You cant use PST files on a network drive, and that's a feature not a bug: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297019

Comment: thanks for your input but it used to be working before switching to Ubuntu, so although it is not recommended by MS, I don't think it is not doable.

Comment: It shouldn't be done, but it can be.

Comment: It is possible to do this but you really, really should not do it. It is very likely that you will lose data if you do: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/01/21/network-stored-pst-files-don-t-do-it.aspx. There is now supported configuration but read the small print please. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297019/